# Vue.js - What are the mouse modifiers for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/). I was reading about the [mouse button modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Mouse-Button-Modifiers). However, I don't understand when I would use them. It seems like it makes more sense to just use the `click` or `contextmenu` events. I must be misunderstanding something.

My question is, in what scenario would I ever need the mouse modifiers?

Thank you

Comment: they do exactly what they suggest;  they limit the handler to the specific mouse button only.  for example, `contextmenu` triggers not just on the right mouse button, but also on the context key on the keyboard, whereas `.right` would *only* respond to the right mouse button.  Similarly, `click` can happen from keyboard commands or screen readers, where `.left` is explicitly the left mouse button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the mouse modifiers are for the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. You can use the `left` modifier with the `click` event and the `right` modifier with the `contextmenu` event. However, the modifiers are unnecessary in these cases.

I wrote a blog post that [explains the mouse modifiers](https://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/vue-mouse-modifiers/) in Vue in more detail. The blog post includes a demo that you can play with the mouse events if you want.